# How to continuously update 2 plots and plotted Camera in same figure (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, plot, computer-vision, matlab-figure, matlab-cvst

My goal is to continuously plot the position & orientation of camera relative to marker using MATLAB.

There are three thing to plot.(1)camera (2)all circle points (3)origin point '*'
Both the camera and points will be moving in each frame.I plotted all these three things in a static figure i.e. using hold on. as shown in the attached figure.

Now i want to plot them all continuously (real time) in the same figure as the values change.Till now i have only been able to dynamically update only one of these things i.e. the circular points for some random values. If I add another plot ,it conflicts.Can you please tell me how to update multiple plots in same figure and the plotCamera.

```
hF = figure;
hAx = gca;
im_pt_2world=rand(3,3);
x_o=im_pt_2world(1,1); y_o=im_pt_2world(1,2); %origin of the calibrated world points
x_ip=im_pt_2world(:,1); y_ip=im_pt_2world(:,2);

hpoints = plot3(x_ip, y_ip,zeros(size(im_pt_2world, 1),1),'ro');


% I added the "ishandle" so the program will end in case u closed the figure
while (1) & ishandle(hpoints)

   %instead of using plot I directly change the data in the line
   % this is faster the plot if only because you don't need to reedefine the limits and labels...
im_pt_2world=rand(3,3);
x_ip=im_pt_2world(:,1); y_ip=im_pt_2world(:,2);


   set(hpoints,'ydata',y_ip);
   set(hpoints,'xdata',x_ip);
   drawnow  %updates the display

end
```

[image]

Comment: Do you really need to solve such problem using `set()`? Can't you just overwrite the plot iself? This will be much easier, with no conflicts between the origin and the little circles.

Comment: @Alessiox overwriting the plot is much slower than updating the plot object's data. Especially noticeable with continuously updating graphics.

Comment: @excaza I agree with that, but my question is: should such plot really be that fast? It'll be like a storm of crazy circles raving around really fast. Is really a problem if such plot is a little bit slower?

Comment: @Alessiox since he wants it in real-time, obviously the answer is yes.

Comment: @excaza I guess you're right. I reckon the `rand()` is just for the sake of demo, given the attached picture.

Comment: @excaza rand() is only for demo. My laptop is actualy slow so I run demo work on my laptop and then final work on a friends laptop :D

Answer (score 1):

The `plotCamera` function (Computer Vision System Toolbox) returns a handle to the graphical object, which you can manipulate programmatically. Changing the object's properties, such as `Location` and `Orientation` will move the camera in the plot. The help example for `plotCamera` shows how to make the camera fly in a circle:

```
% Plot a camera pointing along the Y-axis
R = [1     0     0;
     0     0    -1;
     0     1     0];

% Setting opacity of the camera to zero for faster animation.
cam = plotCamera('Location', [10 0 20], 'Orientation', R, 'Opacity', 0);

% Set view properties
grid on
axis equal
axis manual

% Make the space large enough for the animation.
xlim([-15, 20]);
ylim([-15, 20]);
zlim([15, 25]);

% Make the camera fly in a circle
for theta = 0:pi/64:10*pi
    % Rotation about cameras y-axis
    T = [cos(theta)  0  sin(theta);
            0        1      0;
         -sin(theta) 0  cos(theta)];
    cam.Orientation = T * R;
    cam.Location = [10 * cos(theta), 10 * sin(theta), 20];
    drawnow();
end
```

If you really want to have fun with this, you can supply a function handle to be called when you click on the camera. For example, the function can display the image that the camera sees.

Comment: Warning: `plotCamera` requires the Computer Vision System Toolbox: http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/plotcamera.html. This code will not work if you don't have that toolbox.

Comment: @rayreng, no problem. The question explicitly refers to `plotCamera`, so I am assuming that the OP has the toolbox. But it is good to clarify, anyway.

Comment: @Dima Thank you for the response. I have seen this example and tried it.The problem is not updating the camera alone but rather updating all the three  using set() or any other update function like 'linkdata'.
Initially I tried simply with the origin point '*' and the circular points ,since they are similar in nature as opposed to the plotCamera. But I wasnt able to successfully update both.The reult was only the later plot in static form.

Comment: Oh, I see... In that case, you have `hpoints`, the handle to your green circles. You can also store `horigin`, the handle to your origin point. And you can update `horigin` the same way you update `hpoints`.

Comment: It doesnt work.I just tried it again ,just to be sure .If I comment the code for 'hpoints' then 'horigin' updates just fine.But If run them together, Then output is the static image of the later plot and an error 'Invalid or deleted object.' Most probably It rewrite the original object or so.But I dont know why